# access violation QT PostEvent

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, video, frame

I have the following problem. I am receiving video frames in a non GUI thread in a DLL. I want to show those in a QT app. So I created an QEvent subclass like this:

```
class FrameEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    FrameEvent() : QEvent(QEvent::Type::User) {}

    ~FrameEvent() 
    { 
        free(buffer);
    }
    unsigned char * buffer;
};
```

then I do this for each frame:

```
void frameCallback(unsigned char *buffer)
{
    int size = 1024 * 768 * 4;
    FrameEvent * ev = new FrameEvent();
    ev->buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);
    memcpy(ev->buffer,buffer, size);

    QCoreApplication::postEvent(app, (QEvent*)ev);
}
```

and process the event. Everything works if I don't try to free() the frame in the destructor, but of course I run out of memory pretty fast. I also tried freeing that buffer in other places, like the event() method, but nothing helps. It works without freeing, it crashes when attempting to free it.

Comment: The rule of 3/rule of 5 has nothing to do with it, events are never copied.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough code shown to reproduce the issue. The code you show is not the source of the trouble. It's a horrible mish-mash of C and C++, but it's not causing the crash.

Comment: are you sure you're not creating `FrameEvent` objects without allocating `buffer` ? because as `buffer` has undefined value, freeing it would crash. At least set it to 0 in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is "fine". It's a horrible mix of C and C++, but it's not the source of the problem. Here's how I would do it:

```
// interface
class FrameEvent : public QEvent
{
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(FrameEvent)
    static const QEvent::Type m_type;
    QByteArray m_data;
public:
    FrameEvent(const QByteArray & data);
    FrameEvent(QByteArray && data);
    const QByteArray & data() const { return m_data; }
    const uchar * dataPtr() const { return (const uchar*)m_data.constData(); }
};

// implementation
const QEvent::Type FrameEvent::m_type = (QEvent::Type)QEvent::registerEventType();

FrameEvent::FrameEvent(const QByteArray &data) :
    QEvent{m_type},
    m_data{data}
{}

FrameEvent::FrameEvent(QByteArray &&data) :
    QEvent{m_type},
    m_data{std::move(data)}
{}

void frameCallback(const uchar * buffer)
{
    int size = 1024 * 768 * 4;
    auto event = new FrameEvent{{(const char*)buffer, size}}; // uniform initialization
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(qApp, event);
}
```